# I require assistance with a SQL syntax error

Tags: php

I am writing code for my register and login system, and when I was testing I receiving some errors, there is this one:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE username = ''' at line 1"

Could you please tell me what this means and what to do to solve it.
Here is the code in my update-profile.php

```
<?php session_start();
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$temp=$_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_POST)){
    require 'database1.php';
    $Destination = 'background-images';
    if(!isset($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name'])){
        $BackgroundNewImageName= 'background.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$BackgroundNewImageName");
    }
    else{
        $RandomNum = rand(0, 9999999999);
        $ImageName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name']));
        $ImageType = $_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['type'];
        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
        $BackgroundNewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$BackgroundNewImageName");
    }
    $sql1="UPDATE users SET backgroundpicture='$BackgroundNewImageName' WHERE username = '$temp'";
    $sql2="INSERT INTO users (backgroundpicture) VALUES ('$BackgroundNewImageName') WHERE username = '$temp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$temp'");
    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name'])){
            mysqli_query($database,$sql1)or die(mysqli_error($database));
            header("edit-profile.php?username=$temp");
        }
    } 
    else {
        mysqli_query($database,$sql2)or die(mysqli_error($database));
        header("edit-profile.php?username=$temp");
    }
    $Destination = 'avatars';
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'])){
        $NewImageName= 'default.png';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$NewImageName");
    }
    else{
        $RandomNum   = rand(0, 9999999999);
        $ImageName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']));
        $ImageType = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type'];
        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        $ImageName = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
        $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$NewImageName");
    }
    $sql5="UPDATE users SET avatar='$NewImageName' WHERE username = '$temp'";
    $sql6="INSERT INTO users (avatar) VALUES ('$NewImageName') WHERE username = '$temp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$temp'");
    if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])){
            mysqli_query($database,$sql5)or die(mysqli_error($database));
            header("location:edit-profile.php?username=$temp");
        }
    } 
    else {
        mysqli_query($database,$sql6)or die(mysqli_error($database));
        header("location:edit-profile.php?username=$temp");
    }  
    $user_firstname=$_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $user_lastname=$_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $user_email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $user_password=$_REQUEST['password'];
    $user_shortbio=$_REQUEST['bio'];   
    $user_dob=$_REQUEST['dob'];
    $user_gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
    $sql3="UPDATE user SETs firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',email='$email',password='$password',bio='$bio',dob='$dob',gender='$gender', WHERE username = '$temp'";
        mysqli_query($database,$sql3)or die(mysqli_error($database));
        header("edit-profile.php?username=$temp&request=profile-update&status=success");
}
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements. I hope this won't be used in a production environment.

Comment: Since you are using mysqli,  kindly start by implementing prepared statements before you take this into production. Also you have another flaw, do not store passwords in plain text.  Use php's password hash and password verify

Comment: You have several issues with your code. The second `if`-statement is: `if(!isset($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']) || ...` and _inside_ that if block, you have `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name'],...`. That will obviously fail, since that block runs if `$_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']` _doesn't_ exist. You're doing the same thing further down with `$_FILES['ImageFile']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In insert syntax, you have used where

```
$sql6="INSERT INTO users (avatar) VALUES ('$NewImageName') WHERE username = '$temp'";
```

should be

```
$sql6="INSERT INTO users (avatar) VALUES ('$NewImageName')";
$sql2="INSERT INTO users (backgroundpicture) VALUES ('$BackgroundNewImageName')";
```

also with

```
 $sql3="UPDATE user SETs firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',email='$email',password='$password',bio='$bio',dob='$dob',gender='$gender', WHERE username = '$temp'";
```

should be as below, remove `,` before `WHERE`

```
$sql3="UPDATE user SET firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',email='$email',password='$password',bio='$bio',dob='$dob',gender='$gender' WHERE username = '$temp'";
```

and I would also suggest to read basic document

Answer (score 1):

In the below line you have error:

```
 $sql3="UPDATE user SETs firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',  
         email='$email',password='$password',bio='$bio',dob='$dob',
          gender='$gender', WHERE username = '$temp'";
                         ^^^here you have extra comma
```

Remove the last `,` from the query.

Your query should be this:

```
$sql3="UPDATE user SETs firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',
     email='$email',password='$password',bio='$bio',dob='$dob',
       gender='$gender' WHERE username = '$temp'";
```

And where clause is not used with Insert query.